# Connecting to specific session using remote desktop

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, session

We have a `Windows 2008 R2` server with no active directory, single credentials for all.

It is possible to disconnect from a session without logging off.

**Is there a way to connect directly to a disconnected session while I know its `Session ID` ?**

Clarification: `tscon` is good, but I want to connect directly to the session.

Currently, I log on to all till I find the wanted session.

Comment: If there is more than one disconnected sessions, doesn't the server's UI prompt you for a selection? You can **click** the session you prefer. On Server 2003-R2, **the UI will show you the session ids** and timings. On Server 2012-R2, the session id is hidden but the from the timings alone you can guess which session you want.   (And if there is only one disconnected session, then it's automatic of course since there's no choice available.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note that [***mstsc.exe has no (documented) options to supply a session ID***](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753907%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

But once you have logged in to the Remote Desktop Session server, you can change the session you are connected to by issuing

```
tscon <session id> /v
```

See [MS KB 321703](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321703/en-us) for details on `tscon`.

Alternatively, you might use tsadmin.msc and the "Connect" function from the context menu of the "Sessions" tab:

[image: tsadmin.msc]

As another idea, you could try supplying an *alternate shell* with the [RDP configuration file](http://ls.df.vc/files/rdp/RDP_file_settings.htm) which would run `tscon <sessionID>`, but I am not quite sure it would really pan out as you intend it to.

Comment: This is a nice option, but the question is can I connect **directly** to the required session ? +1

Comment: @Ofiris [***`mstsc.exe` has no (documented) options to supply a session ID***](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753907(v=ws.10).aspx). You could *try* supplying an [***alternate shell with the RDP configuration file***](http://ls.df.vc/files/rdp/RDP_file_settings.htm) which would run `tscon <sessionID>`, but I am not quite sure it would really pan out as you intend it to.

Comment: yup, if it gets to it I guess I will just use the `tscon` option, I thought there was an easy way.
Add your comment to the answer, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @the-wabbit, He is asking for 3rd party apps.

Comment: @the-wabbit, I have `tscon` on Server 2003 R2, but What's the equivalent of `tscon` in Server 2012 R2?